# О сосульках и рожках

Tags: этимология

Большое спасибо за ответ по поводу сосулек и леденцов. В ответе упоминалось, что самодельную детскую соску называли "рожок". Сейчас так называют, насколько я знаю, бутылочку для кормления ребенка. А почему, интересно, рожок? На рог оно, вроде как, не похоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встречал  в  литературе,  что  именно  рог (коровий).  Он  ведь  полый,  использовался  вместо  бутылочки.